# How to merge two tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have two tables table1 and table2. Both tables has multiple columns.

```
table1: serialno , recordno....
table2: recodno,issueid....
```

I want to retrive all the rows from `table1`,
`issueid` from `table2` with condition of `table1.recordno=table2.recordno`

`recordno` from `table1` is primary key. I am using MS-Access database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of the following join:

JOIN: Return rows when there is at least one match in both tables,

LEFT JOIN: Return all rows from the left table, even if there are no matches in the right table,

RIGHT JOIN: Return all rows from the right table, even if there are no matches in the left table,

FULL JOIN: Return rows when there is a match in one of the tables

In your case:

```
SELECT table1.serialno,table1.recordno, table2.issueid
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.recordno=table2.recordno
ORDER BY table1.serialno
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.serialno,table1.recordno,table2.issueid
FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
ON  table1.recordno=table2.recordno
```